# How to install wheel while using a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.9, python-wheel

I followed instructions to install a wheel while my virtualenv was active. When I went to use it I found it wasn't available but when I deactivated the venv it was, so it appears that although the venv was active during the install the package was installed into 'plain old python'.

How can I install a wheel and have it installed into the venv ?

The instructions I used are [here](https://github.com/cloudflare/stpyv8#installing) and this is the transcript of what I did ...

```
(venv) glaucon@rome:/tmp/stpyv8$ ll                                                                                                           
total 18380                                                                                                                                 
drwxrwxr-x  2 glaucon glaucon     4096 May 23 17:49 ./                                                                                          
drwxrwxrwt 42 root  root     16384 May 23 17:49 ../                                                                                         
-rw-rw-r--  1 glaucon glaucon 18797973 May 23 17:49 stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-python-3.9.zip                                                          

(venv) glaucon@rome:/tmp/stpyv8$ unzip stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-python-3.9.zip                                                                     
Archive:  stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-python-3.9.zip                                                                                                
  inflating: stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/icudtl.dat                                                                                             
  inflating: stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/stpyv8-11.3.244.11-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl                                                          

(venv) glaucon@rome:/tmp/stpyv8$ cd stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/                                                                                  
(venv) glaucon@rome:/tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9$ ll                                                                                   
total 24384                                                                                                                                 
drwxrwxr-x 2 glaucon glaucon     4096 May 23 17:50 ./                                                                                           
drwxrwxr-x 3 glaucon glaucon     4096 May 23 17:50 ../                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 glaucon glaucon 10542048 May 17 15:27 icudtl.dat                                                                                   
-rw-r--r-- 1 glaucon glaucon 14416203 May 17 15:27 stpyv8-11.3.244.11-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl                                                

(venv) glaucon@rome:/tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9$ popd                                                                                 
/usr/share ~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox/stpyv8                                                                           

(venv) glaucon@rome:/usr/share$ cd stpyv8/                                                                                                    
(venv) 1 glaucon@rome:/usr/share/stpyv8$ sudo cp -v /tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/icudtl.dat  .                                         
'/tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/icudtl.dat' -> './icudtl.dat'                                                                          

(venv) glaucon@rome:/usr/share/stpyv8$ ll                                                                                                     
total 10312                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 May 23 17:51 ./                                                                                           
drwxr-xr-x 277 root root    12288 May 23 17:46 ../                                                                                          
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 10542048 May 23 17:51 icudtl.dat                                                                                   
(venv) glaucon@rome:/usr/share/stpyv8$ popd                                                                                                 
~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox/stpyv8                                                                                      

(venv) glaucon@rome:~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox/stpyv8$ sudo pip install --upgrade /tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/stpyv8-11.3.244.11-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl                                                                                                  
Processing /tmp/stpyv8/stpyv8-ubuntu-20.04-3.9/stpyv8-11.3.244.11-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl                                                
Installing collected packages: stpyv8                                                                                                       
Successfully installed stpyv8-11.3.244.11
```

When I then try to use it it's available without the venv being active ...

```
glaucon@rome:~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox$ python3
Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import STPyV8
>>> exit()
```

... but not with the venv being active ...

```
glaucon@rome:~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox$ . ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) glaucon@rome:~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox$ python
Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import STPyV8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'STPyV8'
>>> exit()
(venv) glaucon@rome:~/dev/orientation-stpyv8-sandbox$
```

I presume there is a way to install wheels into venvs ? Can anyone tell me how please ?

Comment: Uninstall the globally installed package (`pip uninstall -y stpyv8`), then try again without `sudo`. You don't need `sudo` to install into a venv. You can also try `venv/bin/pip install ...`.

Comment: @AKX thank you very much, that worked perfectly, I appreciate your help. Would you like to convert your comment into an answer and then I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Uninstall the globally installed package (`pip uninstall -y stpyv8`) so it's not messing things up.
- Install the package into the venv, but without `sudo`. You don't need `sudo` to install into a venv (and in general not unless you need a system-wide installation anyway). To be explicit, you can also do `venv/bin/pip install ....`.